# Find sum of the third square of the matrix

Tags: prolog

I need to find the sum of the third square of the matrix. That means that there is matrix like

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
1 1 0 0
1 1 0 0
```

and the result must be 4

I think that I manage to find sum of the elements in the 1D list that I'm looking for, but I can't solve this problem with 2D lists
Right now I've made somethig like this

```
matrix_data(1,[[0,0,0,0],
               [0,0,0,0],
               [1,1,0,0],
               [1,1,0,0]]).

%Start task
%+Test matrix#, -Sum
matrix_main(K,S):-
    matrix_data(K,Ms),
    length(Ms,N),
    matrix_pro(Ms, 1,N,0,S).

%Procedure to go through rows and get sum of each
%+Matrix, +Current row ,+Rows Counter, +Accumulator, -Sum
matrix_pro([R|Rs],Cr,Size,Acc,S):-
    print('    Enter matrix_pro   '),
    row_sum(R, Cr, 1,Size,S11),
    print('   Sum is S11 ' + S11),
    Cr1 is Cr + 1,
    Acc1 is Acc +S11,
    matrix_pro(Rs,Cr1,Size,Acc1,S).

matrix_pro([],_,_,S,S).

%Calculate the sum of each element that we need in a row
%List, +Curent row, +Current index/column in list, +Length, sum
row_sum([],_,_,_,0).

row_sum([H|T], Cr, Index, Size, Sum):-
    Cr>= Size/2,
    Line is Size/2,
    Line =< Cr,
    Index =< Line,
    Index1 is Index + 1,
    row_sum(T, Cr, Index1, Size, S1),
    Sum is S1 + H.

row_sum([_|T], Cr, Index, Size, Sum):-
    print('  Entering with no sum   '),
   % Line is Size /2,
    print(' Houston?? '),
    Index > Size/2,
    print('Aaaaaa'),
    Index1 is Index + 1,
    row_sum(T,Cr,Index1,Size,Sum).
```

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: What *specific* issue(s) are you having with the code you posted?

Comment: Is this as simple as summing the first 2 values from the 3rd & 4th lists?

Comment: @brebs yeah, but the size of the matrix could be different, so it can be 4th, 5th and 6th (as an example).

Comment: @ScottHunter So the problem is that I can find sum of 1D list (like 1 row), but when it comes to dealing  with more than one row (or list) at the matrix everything doesn't work. I mean that row_sum procedure works fine, but the rest isn't and I don't know why.

Comment: Picking certain rows from a matrix should be much like picking certain elements from a list; the differences are a) what you do with them and b) you are picking from the first half *from* each row but the last half *of* the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any square matrix and with (even length sides) you may split the matrix in two halves, then for every row in the second half sum half items and finally aggregate those partial sums:

```
matrix_data(1,[[0,0,0,0],
               [0,0,0,0],
               [1,1,0,0],
               [1,1,0,0]]).

sum_third_quadrant(K, Sum):-
  matrix_data(K, Matrix),
  length(Matrix, Len),
  HalfLen is Len/2,
  length(Upper, HalfLen),      % each one of these lists
  length(Lower, HalfLen),      % will have half the length of the matrix side
  length(UpperRow, HalfLen),   % and will be filled with free variables
  length(LowerRow, HalfLen),   % that will be unified by append/3
  append(Upper, Lower, Matrix), % Split Matrix in two halves
  findall(HalfRowSum,
          ( member(Row, Lower),  % For every Row in lower half matrix
            append(LowerRow, UpperRow, Row),  % Split Row y two halves
            sumlist(LowerRow, HalfRowSum)   % And compute the sum of the lower half in HalfrowSum
          ),
          HalfSums),  %HalfSums is a list of the sum of each half row
  sumlist(HalfSums, Sum).  % Now sum the partial sums
```

Sample run:

```
?- sum_third_quadrant(1, Sum).
Sum = 4.
```

This procedure will not work for odd length sided matrices as I am unsure what would be the third quadrant there.

Comment: Can you explain how this works, particularly your use of `findall`?

Comment: The first `findall` was actually a one-liner to get 4 lists with half the side size of the matrix. When formatting output it also occupies many lines though.

Comment: The second `findall` splits each row in halves and `sumlist`s the first half of each.

Comment: That explains *what* they do (which is pretty obvious); what isn't clear (at least to me) is *how* what you have written accomplishes that.  For example: how is `between` being used?

Comment: You mean the first findall right ? Because the second one seems straightforward

Comment: `between(0,3,_)` succeeds 4 times (binding the third parameter with 0,1,2,3 which I don't need), then `length(L, HalfLen)` obtains a list of HalfLen size. Every time `between` is redone a new fresh `L` is created and the four of them are collected in the 4 lists I will need afterwards (`Upper`, `Lower`, `LowerRow` and `UpperRow`)

Comment: I'm sorry beacuse I don't uderstand all the code that uses find all. Can you please suggest some easier way to do It?

Comment: @GPerun: modified the answer to get rid of the first findall which seems to be the "strange" one . Also commented the remaining findall showing what is done in each step. Basic use of findall is something you will have to learn when programming in prolog.

Comment: @gusbro May I ask you the last question? How does the length work? I understand the first one which return the length of the matrix, but I don't get the length(Upper, HalfLen).

Comment: @GPerun: `length/2` is a bidirectional predicate. You may call it with none/any/both arguments instantiated.  When the second parameter of `length/2` is bound then `length/2` will try to unify the first argument with a proper list of said length. So when the first argument is a variable it will be bound to a list of the specified length where each item is a free variable

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution (for *square matrix of even order*):

```
%        1 2 3 4 5 6
%      1 . . . . . .
%      2 . . . . . .
%      3 . . . . . .
%   Hu 4 x x x . . .
%      5 x x x . . .
%   N  6 x x x . . .
%        1  Hl

sum3q(K, S) :-
    matrix_data(K, Mat),
    length(Mat, N),
    Hl is N / 2,
    Hu is Hl + 1,
    findall( X,
             ( between(Hu, N, I),
               nth1(I, Mat, Row),
               between(1, Hl, J),
               nth1(J, Row, X) ),
             Xs ),
    sumlist(Xs, S).
```

Examples:

```
matrix_data(1, [[0,0,0,0],
                [0,0,0,0],
                [1,1,0,0],
                [1,1,0,0]]).

matrix_data(2, [[0,0,0,0,0,0],
                [0,0,0,0,0,0],
                [0,0,0,0,0,0],
                [1,1,1,0,0,0],
                [1,1,1,0,0,0],
                [1,1,1,0,0,0]]).
```

Queries:

```
?- sum3q(1, S).
S = 4.

?- sum3q(2, S).
S = 9.
```